# R2WinBUGS - logistic regression with simulated data

Tags: r, r2winbugs, winbugs14

I am just wondering whether anyone has some R code that uses the package R2WinBUGS to run logistic regression - ideally with simulated data to generate the 'truth' and two continous co-variates.

Thanks.

Christian

PS:

Potential code to generate artificial data (one dimensional case) and run winbugs via r2winbugs (it does not work yet).

```
library(MASS)
library(R2WinBUGS)

setwd("d:/BayesianLogisticRegression")

n.site <- 150

X1<- sort(runif(n = n.site, min = -1, max =1))

xb <- 0.0 + 3.0*X1 

occ.prob <- 1/(1+exp(-xb))

plot(X1, occ.prob,xlab="X1",ylab="occ.prob")

true.presence <- rbinom(n = n.site, size = 1, prob = occ.prob)

plot(X1, true.presence,xlab="X1",ylab="true.presence")

# combine data as data frame and save
data <- data.frame(X1, true.presence)
write.matrix(data, file = "data.txt", sep = "\t")

sink("model.txt")
cat("
model {

# Priors
 alpha ~ dnorm(0,0.01)
 beta ~ dnorm(0,0.01)

# Likelihood
 for (i in 1:n) {
    C[i] ~ dbin(p[i], N)        # Note p before N
    logit(p[i]) <- alpha + beta *X1[i]
 }
}
",fill=TRUE)
sink()

# Bundle data
win.data <- list(mass = X1, n = length(X1))

# Inits function
inits <- function(){ list(alpha=rlnorm(1), beta=rlnorm(1))}

# Parameters to estimate
params <- c("alpha", "beta")

# MCMC settings
nc <- 3 #Number of Chains
ni <- 1200 #Number of draws from posterior
nb <- 200 #Number of draws to discard as burn-in
nt <- 2 Thinning rate

# Start Gibbs sampling
out <- bugs(data=win.data, inits=inits, parameters.to.save=params, 
model.file="model.txt", n.thin=nt, n.chains=nc, n.burnin=nb, 
n.iter=ni, debug = TRUE)
```

Comment: page 140 of http://books.google.ca/books?id=WpeZyTc6U94C gives you a partial answer. Googling "logistic regression WinBUGS" also gets a lot of hits -- haven't looked at them all but suspect there is probably code there. Can you post what you've tried so far? Also see the `glmmBUGS` package ...

Comment: I am looking especially for R code (package R2WinBUGS) in conjunction with artificial data generation.

Comment: Hi csetzkorn! You know Marc Kery? From the previous question it seems that you are using code from Marc Kery's book :-) He has many examples on this there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is exactly the way to do it. It is almost working, it just required one simple change to make it work:

```
win.data <- list(X1 = X1, n = length(X1), C = true.presence, N = 1)
```

Which defines which data go to WinBugs. The variable C must be filled with true.presence, N must be 1 according to the data you generated - note that this is a special case of binomial distribution for N = 1, which is called [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) - a simple "coin flip".

Here is the output:

```
> print(out, dig = 3)
Inference for Bugs model at "model.txt", fit using WinBUGS,
 3 chains, each with 1200 iterations (first 200 discarded), n.thin = 2
 n.sims = 1500 iterations saved
            mean    sd    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5%  Rhat n.eff
alpha     -0.040 0.221  -0.465  -0.187  -0.037   0.114   0.390 1.001  1500
beta       3.177 0.478   2.302   2.845   3.159   3.481   4.165 1.000  1500
deviance 136.438 2.059 134.500 135.000 135.800 137.200 141.852 1.001  1500
```

as you see, the parameters correspond to the parameters used to generate the data. Also, if you compare with the frequentist solution, you see it corresponds.

**EDIT**: but the typical logistic (~ binomial) regression would measure some counts with some upper value N[i], and it would allow for different N[i] for each observation. For example say the proportion of juveniles to the whole population (N). This would require just to add index to N in your model:

```
C[i] ~ dbin(p[i], N[i])
```

The data generation would look something like:

```
N = rpois(n = n.site, lambda = 50) 
juveniles <- rbinom(n = n.site, size = N, prob = occ.prob)
win.data <- list(X1 = X1, n = length(X1), C = juveniles, N = N)
```

**(end of edit)**

For more examples from population ecology see [books of Marc Kéry](http://www.amazon.com/s/search-alias=books&field-author=Marc%20Kery)  (Introduction to WinBUGS for ecologist, and especially Bayesian Population Analysis using WinBUGS: A hierarchical perspective, which is a great book).

The complete script I used - the corrected script of yours is listed here (comparison with frequentist solution at the end):

```
#library(MASS)
library(R2WinBUGS)

#setwd("d:/BayesianLogisticRegression")

n.site <- 150

X1<- sort(runif(n = n.site, min = -1, max =1))

xb <- 0.0 + 3.0*X1 

occ.prob <- 1/(1+exp(-xb)) # inverse logit

plot(X1, occ.prob,xlab="X1",ylab="occ.prob")

true.presence <- rbinom(n = n.site, size = 1, prob = occ.prob)

plot(X1, true.presence,xlab="X1",ylab="true.presence")

# combine data as data frame and save
data <- data.frame(X1, true.presence)
write.matrix(data, file = "data.txt", sep = "\t")

sink("tmp_bugs/model.txt")
cat("
model {

# Priors
 alpha ~ dnorm(0,0.01)
 beta ~ dnorm(0,0.01)

# Likelihood
 for (i in 1:n) {
    C[i] ~ dbin(p[i], N)        # Note p before N
    logit(p[i]) <- alpha + beta *X1[i]
 }
}
",fill=TRUE)
sink()

# Bundle data
win.data <- list(X1 = X1, n = length(X1), C = true.presence, N = 1)

# Inits function
inits <- function(){ list(alpha=rlnorm(1), beta=rlnorm(1))}

# Parameters to estimate
params <- c("alpha", "beta")

# MCMC settings
nc <- 3 #Number of Chains
ni <- 1200 #Number of draws from posterior
nb <- 200 #Number of draws to discard as burn-in
nt <- 2 #Thinning rate

# Start Gibbs sampling
out <- bugs(data=win.data, inits=inits, parameters.to.save=params, 
model.file="model.txt", n.thin=nt, n.chains=nc, n.burnin=nb, 
n.iter=ni, 
working.directory = paste(getwd(), "/tmp_bugs/", sep = ""),
debug = TRUE)

print(out, dig = 3)

# Frequentist approach for comparison
m1 = glm(true.presence ~ X1, family = binomial)
summary(m1)

# normally, you should do it this way, but the above also works:
#m2 = glm(cbind(true.presence, 1 - true.presence) ~ X1, family = binomial)
```

Comment: As your example is not typical logistic regression,I've added a note on such typical regression. See edit.

Comment: Thanks Tomas T. This is exactly what I needed. I already have the book: Introduction to WinBUGS for ecologist. That’s where I took some code from. I have to admit that I do not fully understand the data generation yet. Usually I would have applied a threshold to the output of the link function (e.g. if probability >= 0.5 then 1 else 0 for true.presence). Does the binomial distribution introduce another layer of randomness?

Comment: BTW ultimately I would like to adjust this for the presence only case as discussed here: Data augmentation in bayesian modelling of presence-only data (can you access it?). I could post this as another question and would really appreciate if you could help me with this ... Thanks so far!

Comment: Hi Christian! Of course, the binomial distribution introduces randomness, this is absolutely needed! There are some factors which affect the probability, but the probability is only a parameter of a "coin flip", it is not result itself yet. One still needs to flip the coin to get the actual result :-) BTW, I've send you an email on Friday (on some address I found at your website), have you received it?

Comment: Tomas I have received your email. Sorry I did not reply yet. Shall we communicate via email reg. the presence-only data problem. Marc Kery has a very suitable example in chapter 20 but he samples several times from each location - I only have one sample per location )-:

Comment: Hi Christian, yes you are wellcome to post other problems on WinBUGS... :-)